# Pass query to report

Tags: c#, dll, interface, crystal-reports

My project requires me to build the Crystal interface such that the OpenRoad dev can use an external DLL to access reports. Ay one point OpenRoad will be passing the SQL query to generate/export the report using my program.

I assign the Query passed from OpenRoad. If the designer has, for example, `column1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6` and the query passes only `column 1, 2, 3, 4` then  columns 5 and `6 are blank on export.

This works if I send all the columns in designer via the query. Is there any property or flag I can use so I don’t have to specify all column names in the SQL query? Or is there another mechanism to achieve this by setting the query dynamically?

Comment: you can use `SQL DEFAULT Constraint` or do you want in c# ?

Comment: you can pass a query depends on your needs but i suggest pass it in CR itself using ODBC.

Comment: Thanx vicky 
but i need this to done in C#  here i have uploaded a snapshot of my code.
![add Query](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4XrLz.png)